# How to pop Navigation Controller iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 navigation controllers. Each with many view controllers.

- **1** `NavigationController (modal Segue)`-> **2** `NavigationController (model Segue)`-> **3** `NavigationController`

Now, how do you go from #3 NavigationController back to #1 NavigationController that I have been before? So I want

- **1** `NavigationController (modal Segue)`-> **2** `NavigationController (model Segue)`-> **3** `NavigationController` (HOW???)-> **1** `NavigationController`

(To clarify, I would not want to go to a new **1** `NavigationController`. I want to go to the one that I used before.)

Help!

Comment: you mean previous..? just use popViewcontroller that back currunt to last one. and pop to rootviewcontroller that back current to first.

Comment: No, I don't want to pop a view controller. I want to pop Navigation Controller.

Comment: Ah.. why do u have so many navigation controllers..

Comment: I want to allow users to navigate back and forth, but when users transition to navigation controller #2, prevent users to go back to navigation controller #1. I have many things for them to read. Each navigation controllers has an unique topic.

Comment: You can have the navigation controller as the the root controller of the window and your first view controller as the root controller of the navigation controller. The user will be able to navigate back and fourth this way by setting any button action as push segue to another controller. To avoid back transition you can hide the back button using self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;. You can easily pop to the root controller also. You dont need so many nav controllers

Comment: Thank you Prathamesh! I used just one navigationController and used this [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO] to prevent users from going back to previous topics. Since the transition isn't model, you can't configure the transition style like Cross Dissolve, Partial Curl, but for now this works!

Answer (score 22):

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: This answer only pop the current view controller.  It doesn't pop or dismiss the current navigation controller.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to dismiss the whole stack of **3** `NavigationController`, you can call this within any view controller in the **3**

**Objective C**

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
```

**Swift 3, 4**

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)
```

This will bring you back to the status before `(model Segue)->` **3** `NavigationController`.

Maybe you can somehow call this in **2** before calling this in **3**?

Comment: in swift3:
```swift
self.navigationController.dismiss(animated: true)```

Answer (score 1):

Use that:

`[self.**presentingViewController** dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

instead of:

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

In a view controller in `navigationController1`'s stack, create an unwind `@IBAction` method:

**Swift**

```
@IBAction func unwindToMyViewController(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (IBAction)unwindToMyViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
```

In your storyboard, you can then hook up an unwind segue from a button in a view controller that is in the stack of `navigationController3`, by dragging from the button to the exit icon…

[image]

from there, select the unwind segue created above. When triggered, the segue will unwind ALL view controllers back to the view controller containing the unwind segue.

Answer (score 0):

this code will pop a navigation controller with all view controllers in it

```
// pop root view controller
UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.navigationController viewControllers][0];
[rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

so you can do something like this:

```
// pop navigationController3 without animation
UIViewController *rootViewController3 = [navigationController3 viewControllers][0];
[rootViewController3 dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

// pop navigationController2 with animation
UIViewController *rootViewController2 = [navigationController2 viewControllers][0];
[rootViewController2 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

With help of this, You can get the  *1 Nav controll* :-

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.view.window.rootViewController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```